# PHP Issue with syntax with html and php mix

Tags: php

I have a syntax problem with some code and I keep changing the syntax but it's getting no-where.

Here is the code:

```
echo '<img style="border:1px solid #f1f1f1;margin:12px 0 12px 0" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://mysite.com/'.$current_user->user.'/'" />';
```

Seems to be around here:

```
http://mysite.com/'.$current_user->user.'/'" />';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
echo "<img style=\"border:1px solid #f1f1f1;margin:12px 0 12px 0\" src=\"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://mysite.com/".$current_user->user."/\" />";
```

**[codepad example](http://codepad.org/RQ8sytkY)**

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<img style="border:1px solid #f1f1f1;margin:12px 0 12px 0" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://mysite.com/' . $current_user->user . '/" />';
```

You had one single-quote too many `'/'` changed to `'/` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<img style="border:1px solid #f1f1f1;margin:12px 0 12px 0" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://mysite.com/'.$current_user->user.'"/>';
```

Part you were hanging up on should be:

```
http://mysite.com/'.$current_user->user.'"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end of line ,try like this:

```
 ...rent_user->user.'/" />';  
            //        ^-----------no <'> sign here
```